# EntityFramework / Databasefirst / Change ConnectionString DesignTime

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework

We are using a Database-First-Approach to generate the application model out of the database. Initially the development has been done by referencing `myDatabase` as schema name.

Now, we also have `myDatabase_test`. During Runtime it is no Problem to change the connection string in order to connect to either database.

However for some larger changes to the database, We now need Visual Studio to connect to the test-database in order to generate an updated model for the debug version of the application.

Altering the connectionstring in `App.config` does work, but when selecting `Update Model from Database`, it seems that Visual Studio can't handle this properly. It proposes to "add" every table in the test-database to the model, despite there's just one additional column in a single table.

i.e. it looks like the designer is considering `myDatabase.table1` to be another table than `myDatabase_test.table1`. (Which they are technically, but not model-wise)

Is there a way to change the underlaying synchronization-source for the Model during designtime, without dropping and recreating the whole model everytime?

Comment: You can manually edit the mapping file.  when you change a database your can add/delete tables and add/delete columns in the database.  It is complicated to compare and old schema of the database and a new schema of the database so the easiest way to make changes is to drop the database and then add new tables and columns.

Comment: Thx. When viewing the `Model.edmx` with an XML-Viewer, I found a lot of attributes `Schema="myDatabase"`. Changing all these to `Schema="myDatabase_test` along with the connectionString in `App.config`  is producing the desired result. Since changing the connection string during runtime works regardless of these references, I think the easiest solution is now to keep the model pointing to the test-database and make sure (obvious) the required transformations are applied to the production database before deploying the application update.